# Disable HTML attribute alignment in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code is stacking element attributes when I format HTML files. Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: I uninstalled the HTML formatter I originally installed. I use JS-CSS-HTML formatter now and it works great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default setting for this is:

```json
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "auto"
```

With `"auto"` meaning:

> Wrap attributes only when line length is exceeded.

The line length is defined in a different setting and defaults to `120`:

```js
// Maximum amount of characters per line (0 = disable).
"html.format.wrapLineLength": 120
```

So setting `"html.format.wrapLineLength"` to `0` should give you the desired behavior.

Comment: This does not answer the question because it disables wrapping in general not the stacking of attributes

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me.
In your "Settings.json" file add the line

```
"prettier.printWidth": 300
```

Comment: Yes. this was the answer that i am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How to debug this issue:

[image: open settings]

Click on HTML

[image: html settings]

Notice the force option, but also take a look a Wrap Line Length.

Test there to achieve desired results, but...

**Test the HTML Formatting First**

- Open document to edit and right click to format.

[image: format with]

- Choose the HTML Formatter

[image: pick html formatter]

Now go back and test each of your other formatters, such as Prettier and TidyHTML etc.

What seemed to work for me was changing the default 120 wrap line length to another value.  I tried 0 and still had same problem, but for some odd reason a value of 20 worked. I don't understand why, it just worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did which gave me a nice middle ground of some wrapping.

- Open Command Palette (`Ctrl + Shift + P`)
- Search for `user settings json`
- Click `Preferences: User Settings (JSON)`
- At the end of this `settings.json` file add this:

```
"prettier.printWidth": 120,
"prettier.singleAttributePerLine": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set all the extensions that have `Wrap Line Length` settings to `9999` and set the `Wrap Attributes` settings to `Auto`.