# How can I put a HTML tag in one line in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, line, break

The VS Code in my Mac pc is automatically breaking the customer HTML tags in new lines. This is making the length of the whole code much bigger.
For example, I want below code in one line

```
<FormInput name="propertyTax" width="43%" height="7%" placeholder="3,200"></FormInput>
```

But the VS code is showing as below.

```
<FormInput
name="propertyTax"
width="43%"
height="7%"
placeholder="3,200">
</FormInput>
```

I tried change wordwrap from settings with no luck.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you have the setting `HTML > Format: Wrap Attributes` set to anything besides `auto`?  If so, that can cause what you are seeing.  And see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42099329/836330.

Answer (score 5):

Just press F1, and type: join lines

Comment: Don't forget to select all. Ctrl/Command + a

Answer (score 1):

You can try switching off any formatters that you have in VSCOde. Go to `Code > Preferences > Settings` and search for "Format" and try switching off "Format on Save" and any other format option that you have.

Comment: "Format on Save" worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Eventually you have to format one day! How can I override the lint formatter itself ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Prettier formatter. Go to *Settings* and search for this: `prettier.printWidth` and change from default `80` to `300`.